# Strange Invalid Parameter error returned in UEFI LocateProtocol and HandleProtocol

Tags: uefi, gnu-efi

I recently started learning UEFI application programming, and I am using GNU-EFI and QEMU as the development platform, following https://wiki.osdev.org/GNU-EFI. However, I encounter some strange issue when trying to access the Simple Text Output Protocol. My code is the following:

```c
#include <efi.h>
#include <efilib.h>

#define CHK_EFI_ERROR(status) \
    do { \
        if (EFI_ERROR(status)) { \
            Print(L"CHK_EFI_ERROR at %d failed with %r\n", __LINE__, status); \
        } \
    } while(0)

EFI_STATUS
EFIAPI
efi_main (EFI_HANDLE ImageHandle, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE *SystemTable)
{
    InitializeLib(ImageHandle, SystemTable);
    Print(L"Hello, world!\n");

    /* EFI_SIMPLE_TEXT_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL_GUID */
    EFI_GUID *Protocol = &gEfiSimpleTextOutProtocolGuid;

    /* Use LocateProtocol */
    {
        EFI_STATUS status;
        EFI_SERIAL_IO_PROTOCOL *Interface = NULL;
        status = uefi_call_wrapper(ST->BootServices->LocateProtocol, 3
                                   Protocol, NULL, (void **)&Interface);
        CHK_EFI_ERROR(status);
    }

    /* Use HandleProtocol */
    {
        EFI_STATUS status;
        UINTN NoHandles;
        EFI_HANDLE *Buffer;
        status = uefi_call_wrapper(ST->BootServices->LocateHandleBuffer, 4,
                                   ByProtocol, Protocol, NULL, &NoHandles,
                                   &Buffer);
        CHK_EFI_ERROR(status);
        Print(L"NoHandles: %ld\n", NoHandles);
        Print(L"Buffer: %p\n", Buffer);

        for (UINTN i = 0; i < NoHandles; i++) {
            Print(L"Buffer[%ld]: %p\n", i, Buffer[i]);
            {
                EFI_STATUS status;
                EFI_SERIAL_IO_PROTOCOL *Interface = NULL;
                status = uefi_call_wrapper(ST->BootServices->HandleProtocol, 3
                                           Buffer[i], Protocol,
                                           (void **)&Interface);
                CHK_EFI_ERROR(status);
            }
        }
    }

    return EFI_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output is:

```
Hello, world!
CHK_EFI_ERROR at 27 failed with Invalid Parameter
NoHandles: 4
Buffer: 0x6A33C98
Buffer[0]: 0x6EB6798
CHK_EFI_ERROR at 50 failed with Invalid Parameter
Buffer[1]: 0x6EB5F18
CHK_EFI_ERROR at 50 failed with Invalid Parameter
Buffer[2]: 0x6AF2F98
CHK_EFI_ERROR at 50 failed with Invalid Parameter
Buffer[3]: 0x6A95C98
CHK_EFI_ERROR at 50 failed with Invalid Parameter
```

First, my program calls `LocateProtocol` to try to find a handle that supports the protocol. However, `LocateProtocol` returns "Invalid Parameter" error. Then, my program finds all handles that support the protocol, and call `HandleProtocol` on each handle. `HandleProtocol` returns "Invalid Parameter" error for every call.

The [UEFI spec](https://uefi.org/specs/UEFI/2.10/07_Services_Boot_Services.html#efi-boot-services-locateprotocol) says "Invalid Parameter" error can only be returned when Interface is NULL or Protocol is NULL, but I am confident that neither is NULL.

Why is this happening? Is OVMF not implementing the specification correctly? Or did I forget to do something? One possibility I can think of is that maybe I need to load some drivers, but I don't know how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma behind the numarg parameter in

```
status = uefi_call_wrapper(ST->BootServices->LocateProtocol, 3 //,
                                   Protocol, NULL, (void **)&Interface);
```

and

```
status = uefi_call_wrapper(ST->BootServices->HandleProtocol, 3 //,
                                           Buffer[i], Protocol,
                                           (void **)&Interface);
```

One more thing you are searching for **gEfiSimpleTextOutProtocolGuid** (**EFI_SIMPLE_TEXT_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL**) but you are using **EFI_SERIAL_IO_PROTOCOL**.

Comment: I see. After I add the comment, my program works well. Looks like GNU-EFI's `uefi_call_wrapper` macro ignores the number of argument, so I do not get any warning / error from the compiler. Also thanks for pointing out my incorrect type for `Interface`